# Java Set.contains(o) vs. List.get(index) Time Complexity

Tags: java, performance, list, set, time-complexity

I'm creating a stock application where I save the history of indices when a certain stock was bought. Currently I'm using a `HashSet<Integer>` to save these values (range 0-270).

In the program, there are a lot of lookups to this history that use `Set.contains(o)`, which is `O(1)`.

I'm considering changing this history to an `ArrayList<Boolean>`, where a `true` at index 0 means there was a buy at index 0, `false` at index 1 means there was no buy at index 1, etc...

This way, I can do a `List.get(index)`, which is also `O(1)`, but I'm guessing will be slightly faster becuase of the fundamental nature of a `HashSet` lookup.

But because of the small range of the indices, I'm not sure if my assumptions hold true.

**So if I am not concerned about space complexity**, which method would be faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your range is small, the **fastest** is to use an array directly:

```
boolean[] values = new boolean[271];

// get the value (equivalent to your hashset.contains(index)):
boolean contained = values[index];
```

It does not involve any `hashCode` / `equals` operations that a `HashSet` requires. This is roughly equivalent to using an `ArrayList<Boolean>`, minus the (very small) call stack.

Array lookup is definitely `O(1)` and a ***very fast*** operation.

You can also consider using a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) as suggested by yshavit.

Comment: *"get the value (equivalent to your hashset.get(index))"* ... are you sure? If I call `hashset.get(index))` I would expect to get .... `index` or `null`, but since there is no such method I shouldn't expect anything :D.

Comment: Haha bad edit since I was assuming it was a map at first :) Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

As well as the `boolean[]` mentioned above, you might also consider a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). It's designed pretty much exactly for these purposes.

```
BitSet bs = new BitSet(271);
bs.set(someIndex);
boolean isSet = bs.get(anotherIndex);
```

This is more compact than a `boolean[]`, taking 34 bytes instead of 270 (not counting headers, which are roughly comparable). It also handles bounds more flexibly -- if you try to set a bit at an index above 270, it'll work instead of throwing an exception. Whether that's a good or bad thing is up to you.

Comment: This might give a good space complexity? But will it have any better time complexity than an ArrayList?

Comment: Updated to add a bit more info.

Comment: This is a good one too. Lookup is ``O(1)``, still very fast but implies a bit more operations than a simple array lookup. Those extra operations are totally negligible in a whole program though.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this data structure, but it does seem like another good alternative. I'm going to accept Jean Logeart's answer simply because it does truly seem like the fastest approach (therefore answering my question), but I'm going to consider using a BitSet in my program.

Comment: btw, I did a quick benchmark, and it seems that for pure throughput, `boolean[]` is fastest, followed by BitSet, and ArrayList taking the rear. More specifically, gets are a good deal fast with BitSet, while sets are slightly faster with ArrayList. For gets, BitSet is about 78% as fast as `boolean[]` while ArrayList is 63% as fast; for sets, BitSit is about 72% as fast while ArrayList is 76% as fast. I can post the benchmark and numbers later tonight if you're interested, but basically, yeah, `boolean[]` is fastest.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that array[index] is faster than [set/list].get(index), otherwise modern JITs will optimize this in a way, that you won't be able to see the difference, unless your app has a very high critical performance requirements.